# How to grant Oauth access to API without cut-and-pasting the consumer key?

Tags: api, oauth

The documentation about the [OAuth API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html) looks very fuzzy on one point: *how the client app is supposed to get the `consumer key` in the first place?*

Indeed, let's say we have a webapp (SaaS) named *FooX* which need to pull data from the Magento API. After the registration within *FooX*, teh webapp would forward the merchant (aka the admin of the Magento instance) toward its Magento store, initiating the OAuth process.

However, looking at the documentation, it seems to me that the merchant is supposed to first to manually create a consumer app and then, manually move - aka cut-and-paste - those keys into *FooX*; which seems to completely defeat the purpose of having OAuth in the first place.

Could someone shed some light on the expected *user experience* associated to an OAuth integration with Magento? Is the merchant really expected to copy and paste keys around manually? Thanks!

Comment: How else would the FooX application know the key to authenticate with?

Comment: The standard OAuth UX does not involve cut-and-pasting tokens; all the Twitter / Facebook / Google add-ons are doing it that way.